# Bash Scripting FFMPEG how to wait the process to complete

Tags: bash, shell, loops, ffmpeg

I have a strange problem. I have a folder monitor with incrontab that launches an automatic transcoding script on `CLOSE_WRITE` state of a file I dropped in. The problem is that the script doesn't wait until the ffmpeg process finishes before continuing with the rest of the script commands. This means that the original file get deleted before the transcoding is finished, which is bad.

First question: 
What is the root cause of this behaviour?

Second question: In a bash script, what is the best way to make sure an ffmpeg process is done before get going with the rest of the script?

Script:

```
#/bin/bash

#transcoding
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "sourcefile push with incron as $1" -vcodec somecode -acodec somecodec "destination file"

#delete source
rm "path/to/file$1"
```

Should I encapsulate my FFMPEG in a while statement?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  What does your script currently look like?

Comment: please show how you call ffmpeg from you script

Comment: Is there an error when ffmpeg encodes the file? Have you tried encoding your test file with the script and can ensure that it works as expected?

Answer (score 0):

first be sure to prevent any stdin input on ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i blah -vcodec blah -acodec blah  result.blah </dev/null >/dev/null 2>>convert.log
```

and issue a `wait` after the ffmpeg command